# Jenkins Blue Ocean Plugin webhook integration from github?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean, github-webhook

I have setup my github integration in Jenkins using the blue ocean plugin. When I manually click the 'build now' button, it pulls my latest commit in  and builds as expected.  I would like to kick-off a pipeline build from a github push, but the documentation and options seem very different when you set up github integration with Blue Ocean.

I have attempted to hit http://my.jenk.ip.xx:8080/github-webhook/ but I get:
'Oops! A problem occurred while processing the request. Logging ID=xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'.  Inside Network properties it shows a 405 - Method Not Allowed.

Also, oddly, when I'm in my blue ocean created github pipeline, click on master branch and in stage view, then click  on 'view configuration' I see the options for non-Blue Ocean plugin created options including ('GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling') but all options checkboxes are greyed out and unclickable.  How in the heck do I trigger this kick-off with Blue Ocean?